# Bus error in my own strcat using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, strcat

I'm doing a pointer version of the `strcat` function, and this is my code:

```
void strcat(char *s, char *t);

int main(void) {
   char *s = "Hello ";
   char *t = "world\n";

   strcat(s, t);

   return 0;
}

void strcat(char *s, char *t) {
  while (*s)
    s++;

  while ((*s++ = *t++))
    ;
}
```

This seems straightforward enough, but it gives bus error when running on my Mac OS 10.10.3. I can't see why...

Comment: Please post some context, most importantly, how do you call the function and with what arguments? How do you define and initialize the pointers you pass?

Comment: You are sure that the memory pointed by s has enough space for t to be added and t is null terminated?

Comment: Oh and by the way, you forget to terminate the resulting string.

Comment: The function should also return something in case of errors while concatenating.

Comment: `I'm doing a pointer version of the strcat() function`.. and how it is now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code

```
char *s = "Hello ";
```

`s` points to a *string literal* which resides in *read-only* memory location. So, the problem is twofold

1. Trying to alter the content of the *string literal* invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. (*almost ignoring point 1*) The destination pointer does not have enough memory to hold the concatinated final result. Memory overrun. Again [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should use an **array** (which resides in read-write memory) **with sufficient length** to hold the resulting (final) string instead (no memory overrun).

**Suggestion:** Don't use the same name for user-defined functions as that of the library functions. use some other name, e.g., `my_strcat()`.

Pseudocode:

```
  #define MAXVAL 512
  char s[MAXVAL] = "Hello";
  char *t = "world\n";    //are you sure you want the \n at the end?
```

and then

```
  my_strcat(s, t);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are adding the text of 't' after the last addres s is pointing to

```
char *s = "Hello ";
char *t = "world\n";
```

but writing after 's' is undefined behavior because the compiler *might* put that text in constant memory, in your case it crashes so it actually does.

you should reserve enough memory where s points to by either using malloc or declare it array style

```
char s[32] = "Hello ";
```